# date part in a trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hello I want to extract month inside a trigger, but I get a syntax error near new is there another way to get month from fdate inside the trigger

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TIMESTAMP new.fdate) into month_extr;
```

Comment: Please show the exact text of the `create trigger` command and the full error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`date_part(text, timestamp)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE) instead:

```
SELECT date_part('month', NEW.fdate) INTO month_extr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried NEW.fdate instead of lowercased? SQL is case insensiteve, but to the best of my knowledge in plpgsql procedures it may be significant.
Another clue - NEW and OLD variables are available only in the row context (so the trigger must be executed "for each row" and not for a statement).

Comment: it is for every row and I changed it with uppercase but the problem remains the same

Answer (score 0):

I would write:

```
SELECT INTO month_extr date_part('month', NEW.fdate);
```

Not sure if your version is also valid.